# Printing bitmap image from thermal printer using Serial input

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I want to print Bitmap image from thermal printer, but image data is from Serial Input. But I am not getting valid print. What wrong i am doing ?

Here is code i wrote

```
#include "Adafruit_Thermal.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
// PIN 6 -> Yellow
// PIN 5 -> Green
// GND -> Black 

#define TX_PIN 6 
#define RX_PIN 5

SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);
Adafruit_Thermal printer(&mySerial);

int count =0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  mySerial.begin(9600);  // Initialize SoftwareSerial
  printer.begin();        // Init printer (same regardless of serial type)

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("1");


  //printer.printBitmap(384, 5, image);

  //printer.feed(2);

  printer.sleep();      // Tell printer to sleep

  delay(3000L);         // Sleep for 3 seconds
  printer.wake();       // MUST wake() before printing again, even if reset
  printer.setDefault(); // Restore printer to defaults
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available()>48){
      uint8_t image[50];
      Serial.readBytes(image,48);
      printer.printBitmap(384, 1, image);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the [example sketch](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Thermal-Printer-Library/blob/master/examples/A_printertest/A_printertest.ino) print a logo? Why do you put your printer to sleep? What printer model do you have? Also a single line bitmap is kind of easy to miss.

Comment: Yes i can print the logo, It was old code so i didn't bother to disable it,
I have https://www.adafruit.com/products/597. I tried printing 5 lines of bitmap so i have idea how small it would be that is why i sent multiple lines a complete 402px height image. i.e. 402 rows